# How can my userbot send a message to the chat discussion below the tellegram post?

Tags: python, telethon

The link to the chat is dynamic and I do not know how to extract the id of the chat to leave a comment, or how to do it in another way

I need my userbot to retrieve a link from the "leave a comment" button or to click on this button to redirect to the chat room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. the library will deal with that, you just use [`comment_to`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html?highlight=comment_to#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_message) in send_message or send_file, passing to it the id of the broadcast message with comments enabled.